# Why does my Query in Sybase database take too much time?

Tags: sql, database, performance, sybase

The execution time of my query takes about 27 minutes. I really don't know why it takes so long. Especially I have an other query with the same output, but this one takes only 1,4 Seconds. 
I want to know what the mean difference between both queries are and why the first one takes so long to execute.

First one, which takes about 27 minutes:

```
select ATTACHMENT_ID from PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT where ATTACHMENT_ID in(                                                                        
            select distinct ATTACHMENT_ID from PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT A 
                left outer join PES_ESB_SHIFTDOCUMENTATION SD on A.MOMENT=SD.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT 
                left outer join PES_ESB_SHIFTTASK T on A.MOMENT=T.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT
                where 
                                                                           SD.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT is null
                                                                          and 
                                                                           T.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT is null
                                                                          And ( 163697831 - A.MOMENT ) > 86400 
            )
```

Second one with 1,4 seconds :

```
select ATTACHMENT_ID from PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT where ATTACHMENT_ID in(                                                                        
            select ATTACHMENT_ID from (
                           select distinct ATTACHMENT_ID, A.MOMENT
                                           from PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT A 
                               left outer join PES_ESB_SHIFTDOCUMENTATION SD on A.MOMENT=SD.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT 
                               left outer join PES_ESB_SHIFTTASK T on A.MOMENT=T.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT
                               where 
                                                                                           SD.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT is null
                                                                                          and 
                                                                                           T.ATTACHMENT_MOMENT is null
                           )tbl1
            )
            and 
                           ( 163697831 - MOMENT ) > 86400
```

How there can be such a big gap ?

Comment: But the joins in both queries are the same

Comment: Generally speaking it helps to have the query plans, table/index structures, and in some cases the optdiag output for all referenced tables; performance metrics of the actual query runs (via MDA tables and/or `set statistics io,time on` can also help); of course we're now talking about an undertaking that's likely 'too big' for this medium of exchange; another alternative would be to explain, in as simple terms as possible, what the query is trying to accomplish, eg, find PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT/ATTACHMENT_IDs where there are no matches in the other 2x tables

Comment: My previous comment assumes this is Sybase ASE; Sybase had 4x different RDBMs products (ASE, SQLAnywhere, IQ, Advantage) so it would also help to know which Sybase product you're using as well as the version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy. 
In the second query there is an additional filter available to the optimiser on the outermost part of the query to PES_ESB_ATTACHMENT.

`and 
                           ( 163697831 - MOMENT ) > 86400`

It looks like this is inside the correlation query on the long query.
This clearly allows the server to cut down on the records it must run through the correlated subquery.

I recommend you look at the query plans, they will look very different.